# How send notifications to all recipients of messenger bot?

Tags: node.js, facebook-messenger, facebook-messenger-bot

I have successfully implemented messenger Bot for my facebook page and I am able to send notification to individual recipient by using their recipient ID.

Is their any way to send notification to all recipients at a time?

If any please suggest me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Facebook's API only supports sending messages to one person in one API call. If you want to send many advertising messages at once, you might want to look into their [Sponsored Messages](https://www.facebook.com/business/help/630500673789880) product.

You should also beware of Facebook's [rate limiting policies](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/advanced/rate-limiting) if you decide to send many messages individually at once.